# Check whether a pthread handle is sleeping

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm writing a sort of same-process thread profiler for my application that needs to periodically check the state of each worker thread to compute its CPU usage proportion.

With Windows Threads, it looks like you can check the running state of a thread with `thread.ExecutionState == 3`.
Is there an equivalent with POSIX threads?

Comment: What is really needed is to 'hook' the context switching functionality.  periodically checking the current state will 'always' say the thread is sleeping as something else is doing the 'periodic checking'

Comment: Good point, but multi-core CPUs exist. How then is it possible for profilers to work on single-core CPUs?

Comment: To determine CUP usage, you need to determine when the thread is running.  Sleeping or not is insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Use `clock_gettime` with `pthread_getcpuclockid` to query the cpu time usage of a thread. There's no need to hook anything or periodically probe the state of the thread. The POSIX clocks API keeps this information for you.

Comment: This unfortunately is not sufficient because profilers generally need to measure things like "time spend with a certain call stack" or "time spent while a certain global variable is true", not just a blanket duration that a thread has been alive.

Comment: @Vortico: Then you should frame the question as what you really want to do, which is collect detailed profiling information, not check whether a thread is sleeping. FWIW the best way to do this on Linux is to use the existing `perf` API/tool. If you can't use it, you could use POSIX timers with the `SIGEV_THREAD_ID` extension (non-POSIX) to make timers for each thread and probe the interrupted `ucontext_t` from the signal handler.